# How to convert NSData deviceToken to JSON-compatible string to remote API

Tags: macos, push-notification, pushwoosh

I need to use the PushWoosh RemoteAPI to register my device. 
 What is the recommended way to send the deviceIDToken as JSON to the service?

The DeviceID is a NSDATA, but to send it to the remote API I need to convert it to a string. 
Which encoding should I use?

```
NSString *tokenString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Leads to strange data and is not accepted as a deviceToken.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app use this method below, I don't think it is a perfect way for it but it works

`NSString *strToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] ;`

Comment: Thank you. In the meanwhile I found out that .description can change over OSX releases. I ended up with creating the hex value byte-by-byte. I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for Remote API register, it might help :)

{
   "request":{
      "application":"APPLICATION_CODE",
      "push_token":"DEVICE_PUSH_TOKEN",
      "language":"en",  // optional
      "hwid": "hardware device id",
      "timezone": 3600, // offset in seconds 
      "device_type":1
   }
}

Comment: Thank you, but the questions was how to convert the deviceID Data properly to a string representation. So KudoCC's answer is OK for me.